# Renaming files with MD5

Tags: web, gulp, frontend

Was going through gulp packages on the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) website and came across this package called [gulp-rename-md5](https://github.com/FroadUED/gulp-rename-md5). Is there a scenario where renaming a file using MD5 is useful and why?

Comment: It prevents duplicates for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a similar tool for cache busting (called [gulp-freeze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-freeze) which adds an MD5 hash of the file contents to the filename).

When you update a CSS or JS file you want users to get the latest version of that file when they visit your site. If your file is named "app.min.js" and you update it, their browsers might not pull down the latest file. If you're using a CDN even clearing the browser cache probably won't request the new file.

I've used gulp-freeze with [gulp-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filenames) (to store the name of the cache busted file) and [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) (to actually update the `<link />` or `<script />` tags with the name of this cache busted file in the html). It's really handy.

**CODE SAMPLE**

This will get your files, use `gulp-freeze` to build the hash, use `gulp-filenames` to store the name of that file, then write that to the html with `gulp-html-replace`. This is tested and working

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    runSequence = require("run-sequence"),
    $ = require("gulp-load-plugins")();

gulp.task("build", () => {
    runSequence("js", "write-to-view");
});

gulp.task("js", () => {
    return gulp
        .src("./js/**/*.js")
        .pipe($.freeze())
        .pipe($.filenames("my-javascript"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});

gulp.task("write-to-view", () => {
    return gulp
        .src("index.html")
        .pipe(
            $.htmlReplace(
                {
                    js: $.filenames.get("my-javascript")
                },
                { keepBlockTags: true }
            )
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});
```

**EDIT** 
I should add that `index.html` just needs these comments so `gulp-html-replace` knows where to write the `<script />` element

```
<!--build:js-->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Any chance you can add code to demo the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

One of advantages is that you can setup your app to cache files with MD5 sum in their name (e.g. mystyle.a345fe.css) for long time (several months) because you know that this file will never be modified. This will save you some traffic and your web will be faster for returning visitors.